# Is there a way to make a looping Function stop when it reaches a particular Column?

Tags: vba, loops, range, counter

I am still quite new to VBA Macros, I know just enough to get myself in trouble. I am trying to create a Macro that takes Raw Delivery Information Data and sorts it based off a unique route code given to each Customer based on their physical address. Currently my Macro will take this Raw Delivery Information Data and sort it by the route codes given to each customer, it will then create a Route Sheet for each different Route Code found in the data.

Ex: If the Raw Data looked like the below:

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDtfK.png)

The Macro would create 3 different Route Sheets within the Workbook:

1. Load Sheet 351045
2. Load Sheet 351050
3. Load Sheet 351055

It would then pull the data from Columns:

A to L and move it to Columns A-E on each Load Sheet.

Below is an image of a Load Sheet with Filled in Data:

[Load Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o12mx.png)

I am trying to make it so that the macro only fills in Data within the range of Columns A-E, but I have manually data that is being added in Columns F-J, which I don't want to be erased when the macro is clearing the contents of columns A-E to make room for new data.

How would I go about making a loop Macro that only clears the Contents of Cells A8 + Down, B8 + Down, C8 + Down, D8 + Down, and E8 + Down, but leaves any data in Columns F- J alone?

This is the Code I have so far for the Loop:

```
'Fill in information - Deliveries and RMAS
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Left(Worksheets(i).Name, 4) = "LOAD" And Right(Worksheets(i).Name, 6) <> "MASTER" Then
            LoadSheet = Worksheets(i).Name
            Sheets(LoadSheet).Select
            Application.Range("A8:E42").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            'Fill in information - Deliveries
            For Each Cell In Sheets(Deliveries).Range("F2:F" & Full_Record_Count)
                If Cell.Value = Sheets(LoadSheet).Range("D4").Text Then
                    Sheets(LoadSheet).Range("A" & (8 + Counter)).Value = Sheets(Deliveries).Range("C" & Cell.Row()).Value
                    Sheets(LoadSheet).Range("B" & (8 + Counter)).Value = Sheets(Deliveries).Range("I" & Cell.Row()).Value
                    Sheets(LoadSheet).Range("C" & (8 + Counter)).Value = Sheets(Deliveries).Range("A" & Cell.Row()).Value
                    Sheets(LoadSheet).Range("D" & (8 + Counter)).Value = Sheets(Deliveries).Range("L" & Cell.Row()).Value
                    Sheets(LoadSheet).Range("E" & (8 + Counter)).Value = Sheets(Deliveries).Range("K" & Cell.Row()).Value
                    Counter = Counter + 1
                    End If
            Next Cell
            Counter = 0
```

Comment: What exactly about the code isn't working?

Comment: Currently when the Macro loops through to Clear the Contents of Column A to E, it is also clearing the contents of Columns F to J. I want it to leave any data in Columns F to J, Rows 8 to 42 alone, as this is where a user will be manually entering in data.

Comment: I suggest commenting out the entire loop after the `Selection.ClearContents` as a test to isolate where your data in columns F through J are clearing. It's not obvious from your code where the problem is.

Comment: Ok I did what you suggested and it still clears out data in columns F-J